# How to find the square root of a number using nested loops?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    num = int(input("What number? "))
    err = 0.0001
    square_root(num, err)

def square_root(num, err):

    for x in range(num):
        guess=1
        next_guess=guess-((guess*guess)-num)/(2*guess)
        guess=next_guess     
        print(guess, end=' ' )
    print()
```

In class we recently started using nested loops and one of our assignments was to use a loop to solve for the square root of a number using Isaac Newton's calculus equation for finding the square root.

The teacher (tried) to teach us how to use the sliding window technique to solve for it but it did not make any sense to me.

The problem with this code is that it will not change the "guess" variable and will instead repeatedly print out the same number. It's also not solving for it correctly. For example, if I were to put 13 as my input, it would print 7.0, which is incorrect as the square root of 13 is 3.6.

Comment: The code you are showing isn't indented properly (incorrect Python syntax).

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting `guess` every time in your loop. You can just move the initialization of `guess` outside the loop:

```
def square_root(num, err):
    guess = 1
    for x in range(num):
       next_guess=guess-((guess*guess)-num)/(2*guess)
       guess=next_guess     

    return guess

print(square_root(49, .001))
```

This converges on 7.0 very quickly, but you might consider accepting a parameter for the number of times through the loop. For example, looking for the square root of 2 doesn't give very good results above
because it only loops through the loop twice. One option is to use the `err` value you pass in and run the loop until the the your guess only changes by that amount. Something like:

```
def square_root(num, err):
    guess = 1.0
    curr_err = guess-((guess*guess)-num)/(2*guess)
    while(curr_err > err):
        next_guess=guess-((guess*guess)-num)/(2*guess)
        curr_err = abs(guess - next_guess)
        guess=next_guess     

    return guess

print(square_root(2, .000001))

#1.4142135623730951
```

With this you can adjust the `err` to get increasingly more accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

I would try looking at how the python sqrt() or pow (num,0.5) function works or look at [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/) It explains the sliding window technique pretty well and I recommend it.